# Unable to start daemon process android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

[image: I am getting this error.]

I'm trying to resolve it from days I tried everything I found on internet, but doesn't work.
Here is list of things what I tried:

1. Changed heap size from `-Xmx512m` to `-Xmx1024m`.
2. Deleted `.gradle` folder from android location.
3. changed windows firewall settings to allow java and android studio to allow public and private network.
4. tried this solution too [Java Platform SE Binary consuming almost 80% of CPU](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/java-platform-se-binary-consuming-almost-80-of-cpu/39cf5aa0-838b-4028-9da0-6c468b3f5956)

Is there anything I can do before I re-install the Java?

Answer (score 0):

Go to firewall setting and disable it. I don't know the reason behind it, but works fine except sometimes.